# Comparing two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 different data frames

DF1

```
ID Datetime  Event
1   07:51      XX
2   08:50      XY
3   09:01      XZ
```

DF2

```
ID Datetime  Value
1   07:55      AB
2   08:54      BC
3   09:05      CD
```

I need to compare IDs between 2 dataframes and then datetime of DF1 will be less than DF2 then event column should come.

DF2

```
ID Datetime  Value   Event
1   07:55      AB     XX
2   08:54      BC     XY
3   09:05      CD     XZ
```

Comment: "datetime of DF1 will be less than DF2 then `event` column should come" — what if datetime in DF1 is later than DF2? What will appear in the `event` column?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to merge the two dataframes and take datetime higher datetime column. you can do this as following

**Create Dummy Data for Testing**

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    "ids": range(1,6),
    "datetime": ["7:55", "9:20", "8:11", "7:30", "11:25"],
    "events": ["E11","E12", "E13", "E14", "E15"]
}

df1=pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df1["datetime"]=pd.to_datetime(df1["datetime"], format="%H:%M")
display(df1)
raw_data = {
    "ids": range(1,5),
    "datetime": ["7:45", "9:30", "8:41", "7:20"],
    "values": ["E21","E22", "E23", "E24"]
}

df2=pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df2["datetime"]=pd.to_datetime(df2["datetime"], format="%H:%M")
display(df2)
```

**Merge**

```py
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ids", how="inner")
merged_df["datetime"] = merged_df["datetime_x"].where(merged_df["datetime_x"]>=merged_df["datetime_y"], 
                                                      merged_df["datetime_y"])

display(merged_df)

merged_df.set_index("ids").reindex(columns=["datetime", "values", "events"])
```